# How to expand a NSOutlineView child?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsoutlineview

Im trying to expand and select a child of an item on a outline view, but the only thing I can do is select the root item and expand only this item and not its children.

I populate an outlineview with directories. Every time an item is expandable, its sub directories are loaded.

I had some help ([How to expand from a child to its very first parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381341/how-to-expand-from-a-child-to-its-very-first-parent/56382493#56382493)) that makes the root selected and expanded.

When expanding an item, I save the location. So, next time the app is opened it will show all item expanded from root to the saved path.

For example, when I select Desktop, close and open the app, it shows Desktop selected and expanded.

If I select dial or mp under Desktop, I can save the path but when open, it goes back to the root and nothing is selected or expanded.

End result would be with dial or mp selected and expanded.

the function expandItem has a parameter expandChild, but it expands everything. I only want to expand until the saved path.

[image]

```
var rootItem = DirectoryItem(url: FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let lastDirectory = defaults.url(forKey: "LastDirectory")
    outlineView.dataSource = self
    outlineView.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.doubleAction = #selector(doubleClickOnResultRow)
    self.progressIndicator.isHidden = true
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.outlineView.reloadData()
    reveal(URL(string: lastDirectory!.lastPathComponent) ?? FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser)       
}


func reveal(_ url: URL) {
    let items = itemHierarchy(for: url)
    for item in items {
        outlineView.expandItem(item, expandChildren: false)
        let row = outlineView.row(forItem: item)
        if(row != -1) {
            let set = IndexSet(integer: row)
            outlineView.selectRowIndexes(set, byExtendingSelection: false)
        }
    }
}

private func itemHierarchy(for url: URL) -> [DirectoryItem] {
    var items: [DirectoryItem] = []
    var current: DirectoryItem = rootItem

    for component in url.pathComponents {
        guard let child = current.childItems.first(where: { $0.name == component }) else {
            return items
        }
        items.append(child)
        current = child
    }

    return items
}


extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem

        return directoryItem.childItems.count
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem
        return directoryItem.childItems[index]
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem
        return directoryItem.isExpandable
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        singleClick()       
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, shouldExpandItem item: Any) -> Bool {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem
        return (directoryItem.childItems.count != 0)
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, shouldShowOutlineCellForItem item: Any) -> Bool {
        let directoryItem = item as? DirectoryItem ?? rootItem
        return (directoryItem.childItems.count != 0)
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        var text = ""
        if let directories = item as? DirectoryItem {

            if(directories.isdir) {
                text = directories.name
                let tableCell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "cell"), owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
                tableCell.textField!.stringValue = text
                return tableCell
            }
        }
            return nil
    }
}







class Directories {
    var name: String
    var subDirectories: [String]

    init(name: String, subDirectories: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.subDirectories = subDirectories
    }
}


class DirectoryItem: CustomDebugStringConvertible {

    var name: String
    var url: URL
    var isdir: Bool
    var prev: URL

    lazy var isExpandable: Bool = {
        do {
            return try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]).isDirectory ?? false
        } catch let error as NSError {
            return false
        }
    }()

    lazy var childItems: [DirectoryItem] = {
        do {
            let urls = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url,
                                                                   includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey],
                                                                   options: [.skipsHiddenFiles])

            var aa: [DirectoryItem]
            var bb: [DirectoryItem]
            bb = []
            aa = urls.map { DirectoryItem(url: $0) }
            for a in aa {
                if(a.isdir) {
                    bb.append(a)
                    // print(a)
                }

            }
            return bb
            //return urls.map { DirectoryItem(url: $0) }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            return []
        }
    }()

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        self.name = url.lastPathComponent
        self.isdir = url.hasDirectoryPath
        self.prev = url.deletingLastPathComponent()

    }

    public var debugDescription: String {
    return """

    - url: \(self.url)
    - name: \(self.name)
    - isdir: \(self.isdir)
    - prev: \(self.prev)

    """
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the values of `url` and `items` in `reveal`?

Comment: on viewDidLoad i call  reveal(URL(string: lastDirectory!.lastPathComponent) ?? FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser)

Comment: Why do you do `URL(string: lastDirectory!.lastPathComponent)`?

Comment: If I use only lastDirectory, it even doesnt show the first level expanded and selected

Comment: Did you check the values of `url` and `items`?

Comment: yes, it seems correct. values show me the names of each path component... but it does not pass the let guard.

Comment: So `items` is not correct? Is the first component a child of `root`?

Comment: when I use: reveal(lastDirectory!), items = [] where lastDirectory/url = file:///Users/rca/Desktop/mp/

Comment: What is the first component of `lastDirectory`? Is it a child of `root`?

Comment: print(url.pathComponents) shows: ["/", "Users", "rca", "Desktop", "mp"]